# Google Cloud Storage 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

**SettingsController.php**:

```
    namespace App\Controllers;

    use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

    class SettingsController extends Controller {

        public function createBucket($request, $response) {
            $projectId = 'myProjectId'; //here I specified my projectId 

            $storage = new StorageClient([
                'projectId' => $projectId
            ]);

            $bucketName = 'socnetfilestestkekdsfa213kfh34';
            $bucket = $storage->createBucket($bucketName);
        }
     }
```

So, I wrote this code in accordance with documentation, but I'm always getting 500 Network Error.

This is my **index.php**:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../config/db.php';

$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => $config]);

require __DIR__ . '/../app/dependencies.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

And this is my project structure:

[image: backend project structure]

Comment: In PHP, error 500 typically means that your code crashed. You will need to look at the errors that are displayed. Do a Google search for `PHP web server errors`. If you are using Apache add that word. Also these lines `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` are mostly like wrong.

Comment: If I remove google cloud code everything works fine, and require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php' also work fine cause I have already tried to change it

Comment: As I said, you will need to look at the error messages. We can only guess as you are not providing details that are necessary to pinpoint the exact cause. Note: The lines with `require` are NOT correct. You will soon find another problem (hint: those line won't work from subdirectories in your server from the root path).

Comment: So what is the correct path for vendor?

Comment: @JohnHanley, look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhcQXFeor9g&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGc_yY90XRdq6mRww042aEC. He has the same project structure as mine and he specified `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: @JohnHanley I've managed to run this code on local server, but when I want to use it on heroku I get 500 Error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've solved the problem. 
As I mentioned `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` was correct. In my case, the reason of 500 Error was an environment variable. For the deployed app you should put your Service Google Cloud Account key config.json into your project. I put mine in a config folder (check my project structure above). 
It means that in Heroku 'Settings' i need to specify 
**GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:** **../config/yourAppName.json**

Thanks this article:
https://medium.com/@naz_islam/how-to-authenticate-google-cloud-services-on-heroku-for-node-js-app-dda9f4eda798